# A wx python application that uses Google maps

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wxpython

I intend to makea wx python application that can request and show the google map (or map from another similar map service) for a specific set of coordinates.

The application should:

1. Show a particular section of the map, rather than the whole screen.
2. Be able to adjust the resolution/magnification of image.
3. Be able to show map view and satelite image.

Where do I start?

Comment: Generally you should start by researching wxpython to see if such a thing is even possible, then look into Google Maps API and figure out how to programtically control it.  However, as it stands this question isn't really on-topic for the site.  Once you've done your preliminary research and have a concrete coding question which follows the guidelines of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then come back and ask it here

Answer (score 0):

Where to start:

```
import wx
```

Now that I have that out of my system :-) ... The first place you should start is to determine if wx can host a browser capable of displaying google maps.  wxPython on windows can natively host IE so you could use that for displaying google maps on windows.  (Dig around in the demo)

I am not sure if you can host Mozilla or Chrome inside a wx application.  So, first determine if you can even display google maps in a wx app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-made widget that can do this for you. wxPython does have a WebView widget, starting in wxPython 2.9, that uses a web browser on the backend and is a bit more robust than the ActiveX version of the widget that was in older versions of wx. You could use that to display the map. Note that you will still need to figure out how to send Google API commands to the wrapped browser instance to manipulate the map.

You might also take a look at PySlip, which can be used to display large images in a tiled manner: https://code.google.com/p/pyslip/wiki/Introduction